# Angular - Method does not await for value to be fetched from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class which calls the following method in its constructor:

```
async fetchSSN() {
   this.userSSN = await firebase.database().ref(`allUsers/${this.currentUser}/SSN`).once('value');
   this.userSSN = this.userSSN.val();
}
```

Basically it takes a the value of **SSN** from the user's node and stores it as a global variable called `userSSN`.

Later on I have a method which uses the value of **SSN** in order to request new data from firebase. E.g:

```
async getLastDocument() {
   firebase.database().ref(`allSSN/${await this.userSSN}/lastDocument`);
}
```

I am having the strange issue that, if I call the getLastDocument() method from another class in my application, the `await` will not wait for `this.userSSN` to retrieve its' value from the constructor of its own class. It will basically try to fetch data from `allSSN/undefined/lastDocument` - clearly not what I want.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I avoid this?

Comment: The code you quoted can't actually be directly in the constructor because constructors can't be async.  Probably the constructor is kicking off that code and not waiting for it.  If so, you'll need to pass a promise to the caller somehow so the caller can wait before calling `getLastDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

You cannot wait for promises in the constructor. What you can do is:

```
// Now, this.userSSN is a reference to a Promise.
fetchSSN() {
   this.userSSN = firebase.database().ref(`allUsers/${this.currentUser}/SSN`).once('value');
}
```

And then:

```
async getLastDocument() {
   firebase.database().ref(`allSSN/${(await this.userSSN).val()}/lastDocument`);
}
```

This way, the "waiter" is on the method, not on the constructor.

---

First things first:

1. According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), `.val()` returns the values itself, so `this.userSSN` is a Primitive or an Object (`number`, `string`, whatever).
2. Therefore `getLastDocument` doesn't need to be `async`, once you don't need the `await`.
3. If `getLastDocument` is having the `this.userSSN = undefined`, means you didn't call `fetchSSN` beforehand OR, what I believe is your case, those methods are inside a `service`, which you may be defining in two different `modules`, making them 2 different instances, then you're not invoking the same `this.userSSN`.

Comment: I am not calling the fetchSSN() method directly. I have it in the class' constructor and I expect it to be called whenever I reference a method from that class. I just call the method `getLastDocument()` and I want the `getLastDocument()` method to try and wait for a value `this.userSSN` to be fetched and then to continue with its call using that value. Currently the method `getLastDocument()` gets called before the method fetchSSN() has finished with fetching the value and thus `this.userSSN` is `undefined` for my request. Can you suggest a workaround for this?